# Reproject Layer without losing Layer Style

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, style

I'm trying to reproject several layers via batch process from one CRS to another. In QGIS 3.6 it seems to work but when I reproject all my layers the layer style gets lost. Every layer has a different style.

Is there any way to reproject the layers **without** losing the layer style?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the translation correctly, follow these steps:

1) make your layer active

2) right-click and select Properties in the drop-down list ...
[image]
3) At the bottom of the interface below - on the left, select the Style button and click on it and in the drop-down list select> Save Style>
[image]
4) In the window that appears, select the button that is in the opposite side of the text (file), click on it and in the new window that appears, save it with the text value of its individual name, after creating a folder with a name like styles

[image]

... and this is your result ...

Comment: Or even faster if old and new layer are in layerlist just copy paste the style

Comment: We are at the beginning of the path and are not looking for easy ways :-), and of course your way is shorter, but this is the second and advanced way ... :-)

Comment: By the way, you first need to stylize the layer, and only then you can copy it: -) ...

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I added the style manually because it didn't took much more time. A more elegant solution would be nice.